# Why do you need to use include when you have declared a using?

Tags: c++, string, include, std, using

I'm learning C++ and I got stuck on why this happends. This code will compile and run perfectly, however if I uncomment the `//cout << foo << endl;` it won't compile.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    string foo = "temporary";

    //cout << foo << endl;

    // Pause then exit
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I solved it by adding: `#include <string>`. Can anybody tell me why this is becuase to me (coming from C#) this doesn't make sense why you are allowed to create a string object but not printing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Idk if you can rely on `std::string` being included in `<iostream>`. Also, don't pollute the global namespace like that. use `std::`.

Comment: Your program is *already* ill-formed, because you are not including the `<string>` header. You don't always get a diagnostic when you make a mistake in C++, but you can only claim that your program "works" if you *don't* make mistakes. The rules of C++ are not enforcible entirely by the compiler.

Comment: Probably because you use the VC++ compiler: https://ideone.com/AAmPhN

Comment: @CoffeeandCode That code seems to work in ideone but not in my project in VS++. Any explanation on that? Is it because different compilers behave differently? One could think there should be some standard :3

Comment: @Caresi Microsoft are notoriously bad at following the C++ standard, but you should include `<string>` explicitly if you're going to use it anyway.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Thanks Coffe! I was thinking that the include was just the way but was just curious of why you were allowed to declare string without it.

Haha well that sounds like Microsoft at its finest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `#include <iostream>`, it's up to the header to include whatever other headers and consequence declarations and definitions it wants - the C++ Standard doesn't forbid it including more than is strictly necessary to provide the required functionality.  Clearly, with your compiler/version, `#include <iostream>` is also including enough of the `string` related definitions to know there's a `template <`...`> std::basic_string::basic_string(const char*);` constructor (`std::string` is a `typedef` to a specific instantiation of `basic_string` for `char`) such that your code is known valid:

```
string foo = "temporary";
```

Still, when you went to stream `foo`, it clearly hadn't seen a matching definition ala `template <`...`> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const basic_string<`...`>&)` that specifies how streaming is to be performed: that's why the compiler complained.  The definition for `operator<<` is probably in your `<string>` header, which is why it really is needed before streaming a `string`.

You can observe this yourself by asking your compiler to output and not delete preprocessed files, which show the translation unit after `#include`s have been expanded.  You'll find the options to do so somewhere in your project's build configuration.

All up, that's why you might sometimes have code work with fewer includes than are strictly necessary.  If you realise you've done this, it's always a good idea to include the other headers, ensuring portability to other compilers and future versions of the same compiler.

Comment: I guess you mean: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3C%3C/

Thanks for the constructive answer! Cleared up alot.

Comment: @Caresi: yes - or [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) - I'd recommend cppreference.com over cplusplus.com - they tend to be considerably more accurate in describing the requirements of various versions of the Standard.

Comment: Thanks! cplusplus.com is the one that google suggest the most so thanks for the tip! C++ is so fun to learn, and so frustrating :D

Comment: @Caresi: you're welcome.  I hope the fun outweighs the frustrations for you.  The better you get at it, the more satisfying it gets - and there's always *plenty* to get better at.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library documents per § 21.3 [string.classes] that using the string classes, their members, operator overloads, etc, requires inclusion of `<string>`. Any reliance that a different header does so, either of your own devices or some other header to include said-same, is non-standard compliant unless documented it does so (includes `<string>`). The insertion operator you're using is described in  § 21.4.8.9 [string.io], but ultimately the same rules apply: include `<string>`.

You can speculate what *may* be allowing compilation to succeed without including `<string>` by avoiding using that inserter overload. Perhaps the operator overloads for `std::basic_string` are included in a manner that is *not* fulfilled by simply including `<iostream>` on your implementation.

That speculation makes little difference in the end, however. That is all it would be: speculation. Ultimately you're code is not well-formed because you're not following the rules per the standard, which thankfully in this case is trivially addressable.